# How do I repeatedly shift and pad elements in a list to get a list of lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]` and want to repeatedly shift the list to get a list of lists.  The first row should be `A`, the second row `[2, 3, 4, ...]`, the third row `[3, 4, 5, ...]`, until the last row `[n, 0, 0, ...]`. The missing elements in the last columns should be zeros.  I was trying to put them individually, but n is >= 100 so manually padding the zeros would take long.  How do I do this?

**edit** same question for numpy arrays, which is what I really have.

Comment: Hi guys. I am really humbled by your quick response. Since I am a newbie, I got confused between lists and arrays. 'A' is an array, when I check out the type(A), I get this, `numpy.ndarray`, and when I print it out (using ipython), I get : `array([[ 24.25,  22.31,  23.62,  22.06,  22.19,  21.75,  20.87,  19.63,  20.  ,  22.06]])`. Based on your solutions, I tried converting the array to a list by `A.tolist()`, but wasn't getting what I expected to. Please help. @John1024, @jedwards, @Vinod Sharma

Comment: If you actually have a new question, you should post a new question.  In this case, the additional info should have been edited into the question.  And you got an answer that takes it into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [ a[i:] + i*[0] for i in range(len(a))]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

#### How it works

To get the i'th shifted list, we can use: `a[i:] + i*[0]`.  The list comprehension does this repeatedly for all the i's that we need.

### Using numpy

`+` means something different for numpy arrays than it does for normal python lists.  Consequently, the above code needs from tweaks to adapt it to numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 5)
>>> [ np.concatenate((a[i:], np.zeros(i))) for i in range(len(a))]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 0]),
 array([3, 4, 0, 0]),
 array([4, 0, 0, 0])]
```

If you want the final result to be a numpy array:

```
 >>> np.array([np.concatenate((a[i:], np.zeros(i))) for i in range(len(a)) ])
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Extra verbose for clarity:

```
import pprint

A = [1,2,3,4,5]

lists = []
lists.append(A)

for _ in range(len(A)):
    last_list = lists[-1]             # Grab the last list element from lists
    new_list  = last_list[1:] + [0]   # (See below)
    lists.append(new_list)            # Add new_list to the end of lists

pprint.pprint(lists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
 [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
 [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The `new_list = last_list[1:] + [0]` just means take the "1th" through last element in `last_list` and concatenate it with a zero to form a new list called `new_list`.

Note I say "1th" because python lists are 0-indexed so "1th" is the second element.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
matrix = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    row = A[i:]
    row.extend([0 for i in range(len(A)-len(row))])
    matrix.append(row)
print matrix
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tam = a.__len__()
cont = 0
rdo = []
for item in a:
    rdo.append(a[cont:tam]+(cont)*[0])
    cont+=1
print rdo
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array that you are creating is known as a [Hankel matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix).  If you don't mind the dependency on `scipy`, you can use the function [`scipy.linalg.hankel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) to create the array with a single function call:

```
In [21]: from scipy.linalg import hankel

In [22]: A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [23]: hankel(A)
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If this is the only reason to use `scipy`, I wouldn't bother--it is a pretty heavy dependency.  But if you are already using `scipy`, then you might as well take advantage of the convenience of `hankel`.